# MVC5: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always returns true

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Our company has SSO site where all our applications gets redirected if the user is not authenticated. The SSO site authenticates the user using Forms authentication. and its been working for all the applications.(ASP.NET applications)

Now we have new MVC5 application created using VS 2013. I am trying to use Forms Authentication. If the user is not authenticated I want to redirect the user to login url ( SSO site). Below is my code.  But when I debug, the user is always Authenticated. 
IsAutheticated property is true, AuthenticationType is "Negotiate", and Identity is "Windows" ( even though in config file its "Forms")

(Note I am debugging in VS with IIS express if that make difference. Also it's MVC 5 application, is it because of OWIN. How do I know?)

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
   <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login"></forms>
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

```
public class AccountController : Controller
 {
   public ActionResult Login()
   {
      string loginUrl = AppSettings.Authentication.LoginUrl;
      string failOverUrl = AppSettings.Authentication.FailoverLoginUrl;
     string securityGroup = AppSettings.Authentication.SecurityGroup;

     if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // IsAutheticated is always true, why?
     {
        var returnUrl = "someresturnurl";
        MyAuthenticator.Authenticate(loginUrl, failOverUrl, returnUrl, securityGroup);
     }
     else
    {
        // Redirect the user if they are already authenticated.
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC5 authentication mechanism has changed significantly.

Possibly all you authentication configuration comes from [OWIN Startup class](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).

[Here is a link where you can find how this configuration may look like](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana)

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

This is a good topic about [ASP.NET identity basics](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

I hope this will help.